# Is there an equivalent to getBoundingClientRect() for text nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom, bounding-box, textnode

Is there a way to get the bounding rect of a text node?

The getBoundingClientRect() method is defined on elements only, and the parent element is bigger then the actual text node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap the text node in a `<span>`, get the `boundingRect` of that span.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, textNode);
span.appendChild(textNode);
var rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Answer (score 37):

If you don't need to support IE8 or older, you can use a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Range) to [select the text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/range.selectNode), and then get the bounding rect directly from the `Range`.

Example (should work in this page):

```js
var text = document.querySelector('#question-header .question-hyperlink').childNodes[0];
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(text);
var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
range.detach(); // frees up memory in older browsers
```

You can also reuse the `Range` object if you're doing this for multiple text nodes; just make sure not to call `range.detach()` until you're done. (Note: `Range.detach()` is now a no-op in [the DOM standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach), though some older browsers will still disable use of the range after its invocation.)

Comment: To test if this will work in your navigator: `document.implementation.hasFeature('Range', '2.0');`

Comment: This approach won't work for text nodes inside input or textarea

Comment: To make 1 thing crystal clear: this is **NOT the height of the text**, but the height of the `textNode` which can be significantly different, I know OP asked for this specifically, but just to unconfuse newcommers :-)