# Is there a way to get the x/y position of a node via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, range, position, selection

I'm aware that for an element, we can use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). However for a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), I'm unable to find an equivalent that can give me a `top` and `bottom` so that I can overlay something at that area of the page. The use case I have for this is on `selection.focusNode`.

Answer (score 1):

Element objects are using the Node interface, therefore all Elements are nodes. But not all nodes are elements, for example text node.

getBoundingClientrect() is only available for `Element` and `Range` objects.

So basically what you have to do, check which type of node `focusNode` will return.
Is it an Element? Nice, `getBoundingClientRect()` should be already available.
If not, and that's probably why you posted this question, you could find the closest element. Most probably the `parentElement`.

Just an example below in case you go with the parentElement

```js
// get the node, in my case it's a text node
const textNode = window.getSelection().focusNode;

let position = null;

// check node type
if (textNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  // it's an element, so you can use getBoundingClientRect
  position = textNode.getBoundingClientRect();
}
else {
  // it's something else, so we want an element
  const parentElement = textNode.parentElement();
  position = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

**Note 1:**
Using the parentElement may result in wrong coordinates, as the text node can be smaller in size than the element containing the text node. `padding`, `margin` and `border` can cause this.

**Note 2:**
There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457044/9184970) answer, where `document.createRange()` is used in order to get position of a text node. This didn't work for me, but I'm sure I just did it wrong. So it might be helpful for you as well

Comment: Ranges are a great start to the solution to this problem. Using the range.getClientReacts API along with window.scrollX and window.scrollY is quite promising.